# Error: "fork: can't reserve memory for parent..." when running a Ruby program in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: aptana-studio

I get this error every time I try to run a simple program written in Ruby:

[image: Running a test program in Aptana Studio 3]

[image: Error after clicking run button]

```
    0 [main] sh 27616 C:\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - fork: can't reserve memory for parent stack 0x600000 - 0x800000, (child has 0x4
00000 - 0x600000), Win32 error 487
   2871 [main] sh 27616 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to sh.exe.stackdump
      0 [main] sh 23176 fork: child -1 - forked process 27616 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
sh: fork: retry: No child processes
1011261 [main] sh 21132 C:\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - fork: can't reserve memory for parent stack 0x600000 - 0x800000, (child has 0x4
00000 - 0x600000), Win32 error 487
1011710 [main] sh 21132 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to sh.exe.stackdump
1093180 [main] sh 23176 fork: child -1 - forked process 21132 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
sh: fork: retry: No child processes
3102783 [main] sh 24012 C:\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - fork: can't reserve memory for parent stack 0x600000 - 0x800000, (child has 0x4
00000 - 0x600000), Win32 error 487
3103149 [main] sh 24012 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to sh.exe.stackdump
3178806 [main] sh 23176 fork: child -1 - forked process 24012 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
sh: fork: retry: No child processes
7188236 [main] sh 25396 C:\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - fork: can't reserve memory for parent stack 0x600000 - 0x800000, (child has 0x4
00000 - 0x600000), Win32 error 487
7188579 [main] sh 25396 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to sh.exe.stackdump
7264650 [main] sh 23176 fork: child -1 - forked process 25396 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
sh: fork: retry: No child processes
15279623 [main] sh 26904 C:\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - fork: can't reserve memory for parent stack 0x600000 - 0x800000, (child has 0x
400000 - 0x600000), Win32 error 487
15280395 [main] sh 26904 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to sh.exe.stackdump
15360615 [main] sh 23176 fork: child -1 - forked process 26904 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
sh-4.3$ ruby -KU -- 'C:\Users\egutarra\Documents\Ruby\test\Test.rb'
15394605 [main] sh 21572 C:\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - fork: can't reserve memory for parent stack 0x600000 - 0x800000, (child has 0x
400000 - 0x600000), Win32 error 487
15394994 [main] sh 21572 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to sh.exe.stackdump
15481542 [main] sh 23176 fork: child -1 - forked process 21572 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
sh: fork: retry: No child processes
16498444 [main] sh 25468 C:\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - fork: can't reserve memory for parent stack 0x600000 - 0x800000, (child has 0x
400000 - 0x600000), Win32 error 487
16499102 [main] sh 25468 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to sh.exe.stackdump
16582998 [main] sh 23176 fork: child -1 - forked process 25468 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
sh: fork: retry: No child processes
18599570 [main] sh 27496 C:\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - fork: can't reserve memory for parent stack 0x600000 - 0x800000, (child has 0x
400000 - 0x600000), Win32 error 487
18600541 [main] sh 27496 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to sh.exe.stackdump
18678620 [main] sh 23176 fork: child -1 - forked process 27496 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
sh: fork: retry: No child processes
22696812 [main] sh 21064 C:\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - fork: can't reserve memory for parent stack 0x600000 - 0x800000, (child has 0x
400000 - 0x600000), Win32 error 487
22697451 [main] sh 21064 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to sh.exe.stackdump
22774018 [main] sh 23176 fork: child -1 - forked process 21064 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
sh: fork: retry: No child processes
30789517 [main] sh 26360 C:\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - fork: can't reserve memory for parent stack 0x600000 - 0x800000, (child has 0x
400000 - 0x600000), Win32 error 487
30790161 [main] sh 26360 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to sh.exe.stackdump
30866864 [main] sh 23176 fork: child -1 - forked process 26360 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Comment: What have you tried exactly in order to fix your problem?  I am not going to list dozens of possible solutions if you already tried 11 of them.

Comment: I'm really not sure what the problem is, so I haven't really tried anything. I have checked whether cygwin works and it appears to work just fine. That is, when I open a cygwin64 terminal and used the sh command I don't get any such errors

Answer (score 1):

My problem was fixed after updating to the latest version of Cygwin. I'm not sure what the problem was, but updating Cygwin fixed it.